How can I programmatically capture the output from the current cell in a function called from Jupyter / ipython?
I am trying to implement an ipython's magic cell function that takes the code from the current cell, runs it, and caches its output (in rich format) to a file. The final objective of my magic function is a bit more elaborate but I hope this description suffices.
In order to achieve this, I want my magic function to use a helper function which I call capture_output, implemented in some python module, example.py, which allows me to capture the output from my current cell in a jupyter notebook, something like this:
>>> import example as ex

>>> cell_code = "3+2"

>>> output = ex.capture_output (cell_code)

>>> output.show()

5

In this case, the captured output is just text, i.e., the result of 3+2. However, if the cell displays an image, then the captured output would be the displayed image:
>>> import example as ex

>>> cell_code = """
import matplolib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot ([1,2,3,4])
"""

>>> output = ex.capture_output (cell_code)

>>> output.show()


I know we have the magic %%capture, and we can run it using "run_cell_magic". However, this produces errors when implemented inside a python module that is being called from an ipython session / Jupyter notebook.
For example, if I have the following code in "example.py":
from IPython import get_ipython

def capture_output (code):
    get_ipython().run_cell_magic("capture", "output", code)
    return output

And then run it from an ipython session:
import example as ex

output = ex.capture_output ("3+2")
output.show()

I get the following error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 ex.capture_output ("3+2")

File example.py:6, in capture_output (code)
      4 def capture_output (code):
      5     get_ipython().run_cell_magic("capture", "output", code)
----> 6     return output

NameError: name 'output' is not defined


I think you are making an XY problem here. Maybe. It's hard to tell for sure yet because your example code is flawed here. For now we can stick with your example code of 3 + 2. This definitely makes it easier. I'll have to get back to you later though when I have some time to test. But I believe you aren't running the code yet. Plus there is an easier way to do this, I believe, at least with this example for now. Plus I don't get how/why you'll distinguish "my current cell". Your current code is not getting near that problem and I think...

 there may also be better ways to get at that without what you are pursuing here. For all those reasons that is why I mention the problem XY. As for the simple example code you have now, you don't need to invoke Jupyter because you can calculate the code that would be in your notebook anyway, see here, here, and here. But again, I don't think that is what you actually want to do if you instead get back to ...

 addressing the goal you briefly touch on at the start of the text in your post, stated as "allows me to capture the output from my current cell in a jupyter notebook".

And note, it your output happened to be from a previous cell, and importantly involves numbers like you 3+2 example, you can take advantage of iPython/Jupyter's output caching system, see here, here, and here.

Thanks @Wayne I will edit my question to add more clarity, although I will need some time for that. Your first link already pointed to a solution that might be feasible, although I believe that using exec won't work in my case, since I need the code variables to be in the same name space as that of the notebook the module is imported from. I will clarify all this in my edit.

"since I need the code variables to be in the same name space as that of the notebook the module is imported from." This makes me think your question here is getting farther away from what you really want to do. I think you are just seeking different ways to run a notebook and collect the output in separate location, which jupytext in combination with nbformat is good for, or to use %run my_notebook.ipynb.

Thanks @Wayne, I just added a bit more context to my question. The final goal might still not be clear, but I don't want to complicate my question too much, and since you already provided a good answer to it below, I think I will leave as it is for now.

You want the following for example.py
from IPython import get_ipython

def capture_output (code):
    get_ipython().run_cell_magic("capture", "output", code)
    return get_ipython().user_ns['output']

Details
You put example.py as the following:
from IPython import get_ipython

def capture_output (code):
    get_ipython().run_cell_magic("capture", "output", code)
    return output

The issue is that you were expecting output to be something and you returned it; however, as written, it wasn't anything. Or at least not accessible to you. The output from the cell magic run was only accessible in the namespace of the where that ipython code was run, which is not the main namespace where you are running your code that is passing in code and expecting it returned.
You can though access IPython's user namespace as user_ns if you add to your code.
This example in response to 'How to make caller's namespace available to IPython's magic inside imported function?' using a line magic works and get me thinking along the lines of user_ns. However, the cited resource was no longer available. The answers to 'IPython notebook: How to write cell magic which can access notebook variables?' also brought up user_ns, but it wasn't obvious. Luckily, the post 'Let's Write an IPython Extension the Hard Way' by Sebastian Witowski pointed me in the correct direction & made me think ipython.user_ns may be the same as get_ipython().user_ns.


Related resources for those ending up in this thread:

my answer to 'How do I construct a python function where the input in python code and output is ipython rich output (in HTML)?'

my answer to 'Get value and type of python variable similar to Jupyter behavior'

my answer to 'python/sage: how to get the last expression?'

SO post about Jupyter/IPython's output caching system to access previous output in running notebook or IPython console/interpreter

Documentation about Jupyter/IPython's output caching system to access previous output in running notebook or IPython console/interpreter

an old answer of mine illustrating using Jupyter/IPython's output caching system



Thank you very much. This is indeed a very useful answer. I think the issue regarding not having access to the variable "output" has to do with the hard-coded value of stack_depth to 2, in the implementation of run_cell_magic. There is a comment in that implementation indicating that this might not work in certain cases. I think one such case is when we call run_cell_magic from a function written in a module, rather than written in the notebook. Your explanation is consistent with this. I filed an issue in ipython since I think this leads to confusing behaviour in many cases.

Just adding one alternative to the answer provided by @Wayne, based also on his comments to my question, the following solution is also acceptable:
from IPython.utils.capture import capture_output
from IPython import get_ipython

def capture_output(cell):
    with capture_output(True, True, True) as output:
        get_ipython().run_cell(cell)
    return output

The difference here is that we are calling run_cell in the context of capture_output rather than calling run_cell_magic. If we look at the implementation of run_cell_magic, it ends up doing the same, so we can write it more directly as shown in this answer.

Good explanation. Plus this handles rich output. For context, I think that was adapted from my answer to 'How do I construct a python function where the input in python code and output is ipython rich output (in HTML)?', which has a bit on dealing with the rich output, like plot example in original post, specifically, and I link to a posted notebook dealing with how to show the plot object again collected with that function. I added additional resources linking there, ...

 to the bottom of my answer, as well.
